# How to extract all the cells between two other cells in Pandas from the column with most cells between these two other cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple financial statements and not all of them have the same entries - some have more entries than others - and I'd like to consolidate them all into a single one that has all of the entries.

I was able to do it manually in Excel since it's not that many, but I'd like to have the computer do it to double check I got them all.

So, here's what I did:
I created a dataframe where each column has the entry names from one of the financial statements.

| FinancialStatement1 | FinancialStatement2 | FinancialStatement3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| REVENUES | REVENUES | REVENUES |
| Revenue1 | Revenue1 | Revenue1 |
| Revenue2 | Revenue2 | Revenue2 |
| EXPENSES | EXPENSES | Revenue3 |
| Expense1 | Expense1 | EXPENSES |
| Expense2 | PROFIT | Expense1 |
| Expense3 | - | Expense2 |
| PROFIT | - | PROFIT |
| - | - | - |

My idea was to run a script that would analyse the number of cells between two of the group titles and return to a 'Consolidated' column all of the strings between these two values, including the first, but not the last.

My end result would look like this:

| FinancialStatement1 | FinancialStatement2 | FinancialStatement3 | Consolidated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REVENUES | REVENUES | REVENUES | REVENUES |
| Revenue1 | Revenue1 | Revenue1 | Revenue1 |
| Revenue2 | Revenue2 | Revenue2 | Revenue2 |
| EXPENSES | EXPENSES | Revenue3 | Revenue3 |
| Expense1 | Expense1 | EXPENSES | EXPENSES |
| Expense2 | PROFIT | Expense1 | Expense1 |
| Expense3 | - | Expense2 | Expense2 |
| PROFIT | - | PROFIT | Expense3 |
| - | - | - | PROFIT |

I'm a beginner in Pandas and, so far, here's what I came up with by searching here in stack:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file)
df['Consolidated']=0
df.head()

df['Consolidated'].iloc[1] = df['FinancialStatement1'][df['FinancialStatement1'].between(
    'REVENUES', 'EXPENSES',
    inclusive=False
    )].tolist()
```

However, this code gives me `"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"`.
I tried using only df.iloc[3,0] but it also doesn't work. Anyway, this code won't do what I want anyway since it doesn't pick the list with most items between the two group titles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just get a list of all line items needed to cover all financial statments, you can do the following

```
l = list(set(df.unstack().values.tolist()))
l.sort()
l.remove('-')
print(l)

['EXPENSES', 'Expense1', 'Expense2', 'Expense3', 'PROFIT', 'REVENUES', 'Revenue1', 'Revenue2', 'Revenue3']
```

If you want to just pull out the needed Revenues:

```
revs = [val for val in l if 'Revenue' in val]
revs.sort()
print(revs)

['Revenue1', 'Revenue2', 'Revenue3']
```

If you want to just pull out the needed Expenses:

```
exps = [val for val in l if 'Expense' in val]
exps.sort()
print(exps)

['Expense1', 'Expense2', 'Expense3']
```

You can piece together the data how you want an add the column to existing df or create a new one

```
line_items =['REVENUES'] + revs + ['EXPENSES'] + exps + ['PROFIT']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'consolidated':line_items})
df_final = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df_final.columns = ['FinancialStatement1', 'FinancialStatement2', 'FinancialStatement3', 'consollidated']
df_final

  FinancialStatement1 FinancialStatement2 FinancialStatement3 consollidated
0            REVENUES            REVENUES            REVENUES      REVENUES
1            Revenue1            Revenue1            Revenue1      Revenue1
2            Revenue2            Revenue2            Revenue2      Revenue2
3            EXPENSES            EXPENSES            Revenue3      Revenue3
4            Expense1            Expense1            EXPENSES      EXPENSES
5            Expense2              PROFIT            Expense1      Expense1
6            Expense3                   -            Expense2      Expense2
7              PROFIT                   -              PROFIT      Expense3
8                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN        PROFIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SET of all the entries in the column.  Python SET will eliminate duplicates.  Then you cast to a list and create a pd with the superset of all the entries and join it back to the dataframe.

```
s = set()
for col in df.columns:
    s |= set(df[col])
l = sorted(list(s - set(['-'])))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['Consolidated'])
df = df.join(df1,how='outer').replace(np.nan,'-')
```

|  | FinancialStatement1 | FinancialStatement2 | FinancialStatement3 | Consolidated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | REVENUES | REVENUES | REVENUES | EXPENSES |
| 1 | Revenue1 | Revenue1 | Revenue1 | Expense1 |
| 2 | Revenue2 | Revenue2 | Revenue2 | Expense2 |
| 3 | EXPENSES | EXPENSES | Revenue3 | Expense3 |
| 4 | Expense1 | Expense1 | EXPENSES | PROFIT |
| 5 | Expense2 | PROFIT | Expense1 | REVENUES |
| 6 | Expense3 | - | Expense2 | Revenue1 |
| 7 | PROFIT | - | PROFIT | Revenue2 |
| 8 | - | - | - | Revenue3 |

Comment: @acgarcia00 hi.  If this answers your question, kindly check the tick to accept the answer.  Thanks.